# Floating windows in Android Studio don't maintain position or size after closing and reopening

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio with two monitors. On my second monitor I have two floating and pinned windows. After Resizing and positioning they look like so:

[image]

However, if I close Android Studio and reopen it the windows will reset, always, to these little boxes in the center of my main Android Studio window:

[image]

Has anyone encountered this issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I dragged each window to their respective places. Right clicked on the title bar and unchecked "Pinned Mode" then right clicked on the title bar and checked "Pinned Mode."

I was also able to confirm the change stuck by checking `%AndroidWorkSpaceDir%\%ProjectDir%\.idea\workspace.xml` and verifying the `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` values for the following nodes:

```
<component name="ToolWindowManager">
   <layout>
        <window_info ... />
        <window_info ... />
   </layout>
   <layout-to-restore>
        <window_info ... />
        <window_info ... />
   </layout-to-restore>
</component>
```